# How do I call a function in a Tkinter Frame class from main?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How do I call this my_func function from inside main?
This is the error I get after running it:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)
        def my_func():
            my_label.config(text = 'My New Label')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('460x350')
    top_frame = Frame(root)
    my_label = Label(top_frame, text='My Label')
    Window().my_func()
    top_frame.pack()
    my_label.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your error is in self.master.config(menu=menu) (master is None).

Comment: What is the point of defining `my_func()` inside `Window` class because it has nothing to do with any class members?

Answer (score 0):

Remarks in code explain the few changes necessary to make your code functional.

Basically `my_func` indentation required modification with the addition of `self`

Also, `root` needed to be passed to `Window` class.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        # This is not necessary since master has already been passed to Frame 
        # self.master = master
        menu = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu = menu)

    def my_func(self):
        my_label.config(text = 'My New Label')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('460x350')
    top_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    my_label = tk.Label(top_frame, text='My Label')

    # Instantiate Window class as 'mywindow' and pass root as master
    Window(root).my_func()
    # Or access 'my_func' like this
    # mywindow = Window(root)
    # mywindow.my_func()
    top_frame.pack()
    my_label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```